# Where to have onTouchListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning how to do a simple game and I have a MainActivity class where I implements onTouchListener and then I have a GameLoop class that extends SurfaceView and implements Runnable. The GameLoop class also handles the rest of the classes like a manager class for the moving sprites. It's inside the GameLoop class that the drawing stuff on the canvas is done.

What I need to do is to draw lines with my finger tips, but I'm not sure how I should handle the values from the onTouchListeners to be able to draw lines. I guess it won't work if I have the onTouchListener inside the MainActivity!? And I guess I can't implement it to GameLoop class since I already implement Runnable!?

How can I implement the onTouchListener to the GameLoop class if I'm already implementing something else? I guess I cant implement more than one interface? When I try I get errors in Eclipse!

Comment: An onTouchListener is applied to whatever view you want to recognize your touch events.  I would suggest, however, that you clarify your thoughts and ask an actual and specific question.  What it sounds like now is that you're asking for help designing your game, and StackOverflow ain't the place for that kind of help.

Comment: No I'm not asking for help to design a game! I need some help how and where I can implement the onTouchListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java class can only *extend* one class but it can *implement* any number of interfaces. Simply comma-separate the interface names you wish to implement in your class declaration:

```
public MyClass extends BaseClass implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, FooListener
```

You could also use an anonymous listener:

```
someView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Another option is to override [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) in your Activity and pass the motion event to whatever class you wish to handle the touch event.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but when I write like this: public class GameLoop extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, OnTouchListener { I get an red line below OnTouchListener and one of the options is to import OnTouchListener, but nothing happens when I click on that option, that's why I'm confused and didn't thought it was possible to have more than one interface! What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you be kind to explain how you mean with the override part? Right now I'm testing to set the values from the OnTouchListener like this. gameLoop.xStart. Is this a good option?

Comment: It's seems that the reason why I couln't implement the OnTouchListener, was because I already implemented it to the MainActivity class.

Comment: What I meant by override is to provide your own implementation of a method instead of the standard one. Read a Java tutorial on how to override methods or post another question (although I'm sure it's already answered on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Implement your listener on the view your finger is drawing against, using `setOnTouchListener()` and pass in your listener class. Since you know there is a `MotionEvent` object passed into `onTouch()` then you will need to utilize that object by using `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` to determine where your pointer, in this case your finger, is at on the screen. Notice you will need to deliberately handle multi-touch if you need that function. These are all documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Do attaching your listener in your activity, and you can pass that `MotionEvent` object to your view to extract useful information and call drawing methods you define inside your view object and `invalidate()`. This assumes you want to concentrate all drawing methods in that view class.

Alternatively, you can draw stuff directly in your activity, maybe putting some new views or other stuff. As long as you have the `MotionEvent` object, you will have the coordinates of your pointers(finger) and you can use that information to draw.

The activity in which you want to `setOnTouchListener()` will most likely be the activity that is directly associated with the view you draw your line against, either by having a relatively persistent reference to that view, or by binding to that view using `setContentView()`.

You can't implement more than one interface in the same class in Java. This is not an Eclipse or ADT issue. If you do want to do that however, extend a interface and add new stuff to it. Using inheritance you literally add multiple interfaces together.